# clang: cancel effect of the -x option for subsequent files

Tags: clang

clang has an option, `-x`, which can be used to specify the language of subsequent source files passed to it.  This caused problems when used like this:

```
clang -x c++ one.cc a.o b.o c.o
```

`clang` will try to interpret the object files `a.o`, `b.o`, `c.o` as source code.

Is there a way to cancel the effect of the -x option so I can pass object files on the same command line?

```
clang -x c++ one.cc SOMEOPTION a.o b.o c.o
```

What should `SOMEOPTION` be to allow clang to interpret the .o files as object files?

I need to use this convoluted command line because I am using a system that calls the compiler automatically to compile some code it generates and there are limits to how much it can be hacked.

Answer (score 0):

could you put the arguments the other way 'round

```
clang a.o b.o c.o -x c++ one.cc
```

or compile each file and then link them in a later run

```
clang -x c++ one.cc -o one.cc.o
clang a.o b.o c.o one.cc.o
```

This is how in my experience it is actualy used.